# Is there a way to embed a fully contained html table into xaringan slides?

Tags: xaringan

I am trying to embed an html table produced using `kable`. The code producing the table takes a while to run, so I don't want to include it in my `xaringan` slides.
Using `xfun::file_string()` to read a saved txt file removes the formatting of the table. Is there a way to embed a saved and self-contained table into the slides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the chunk option `results='asis'`:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
xfun::file_string('your-table.html')
```
````